Let $C' = \{a \in G : (ax)^2 = (xa)^2 \forall x \in G\}$, prove $C'$ is a subgroup
For $G$ a general group, let $C' = \{a \in G : (ax)^2 = (xa)^2 , \forall x \in G\}$. Prove $C'$ is a subgroup.
There's a proof that $C'$ is closed under inverses from 2014, but I was able to solve that part; what I can't prove is that $C'$ is closed under multiplication.

Write $x=ya^{-1}$. Then the condition implies (just plug in and simplify) that $ay^2=y^2a$. So $C'$ is the intersection $\cap C_G(y^2)$ as $y$ ranges over $G$. As the intersection of subgroups, it's a subgroup.

Let $a,b\in G$ then for all $x\in G$
$$(ax)^2=(xa)^2\land (bx)^2=(xb)^2$$
thus using associativity
$$(abx)^2=(a\cdot \underbrace{bx}_{"x"})^2=(bx\cdot a)^2=(b\cdot \underbrace{xa}_{"x"})^2=(xa\cdot b)^2=(xab)^2$$
as we wanted to show

By hypothesis $axax=xaxa$ and $bxbx=xbxb$ for all $x\in G$.
The key is that $x$ here is really a "dummy variable". It can be any element of $G$.
Select arbitrary $x_0\in G$. It suffices to prove $abx_0abx_0=x_0abx_0ab$.
To see this, plug $x=bx_0$ in $axax=xaxa$ we see
$$abx_0abx_0=bx_0abx_0a  $$.
Plug $x=x_0a$ in $bxbx=xbxb$ we see $$bx_0abx_0a=x_0abx_0ab . $$
Comparing the two equalities in displayed style gives the desired result.
